# Renaming and rearranging filenames with no delimiters

Tags: batch-rename

I have already created the code that works, but it took me a while, so I thought I'd share.

I needed to rename a directory of files with the following filename format:  `Dailymmddyyyy.csv`.

I needed the filename format to be: `yyyymmdd.csv`

Here is the code:

```
::This code takes a directory (c:\batch) with files in the following format ::Dailymmddyyyy.csv, and changes them to yyyymmdd.csv:

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%i in (c:\batch\Daily*) do (
  set filename="%%~ni"
  set year=!filename:~10!
  ren "%%~i" "!year!!filename:~6,4!%%~xi"    
)
endlocal
```

The `~10` and `~6,4` were not the numbers I expected to use, but it works.  There is still something I'm missing in my understanding.